# My mounted EBS volume is not showing up

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Trying to mount a 384G volume from old instance to a newly configure instance (8G). Attached 384G volume shows up on `lsblk` but on `df -h` it doesn't come up at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-111-111-111 ~]$ lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvdf  202:80   0  384G  0 disk 
xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 disk /

[ec2-user@ip-10-111-111-111 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  1.5G  6.4G  19% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

**Note: On EC2 instance dashboard it displays**

Root device: /dev/sda1
Block devices: /dev/sda1  /dev/sdf

Comment: For reference, Amazon has a page detailing how to mount EBS volumes here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `df -k` will only show mounted volumes.
You will need to mount your volume first, like this `mount /dev/xvdf /mnt` then you will be able to access it's content from `/mnt` and see it when typing `df -k`

Answer (score 18):

For those landing here after not finding their `xvdf` devices on aws ec2 c5 or m5 instances, it's renamed to `/dev/nvme...` as per the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html)

> For C5 and M5 instances, EBS volumes are exposed as NVMe block
>   devices. The device names that you specify are renamed using NVMe
>   device names (/dev/nvme[0-26]n1). For more information, see Amazon EBS
>   and NVMe.

Answer (score 0):

[image]If this is windows follow this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-windows.html#recognize-expanded-volume-windows-disk-management